# jQuery Accordion for ipad single tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, touch, accordion

I came across this problem with `jQuery Accordion` where I couldn't find the way to make `accordion ul li` to slide down on a single tap rather then doing dbl tap(for mouseover and click).

I've tried removing `mouseover` class from `accordion` and all the links but it didn't really work. I was wondering if anyone have fixed this issue?

Thanks!